# how to create pixel art like that?

Tags: javascript, shell, dart, pixel

I'm creating a pokémon fighting project in Dart.
I recently came across an interesting github profile where the guy had listed all the pokémons by generation with his pixel art.
The idea is to do curl -s followed by the pokémon link from your terminal and it displays the pokémon.

https://github.com/shinya/pokemon-terminal-art/tree/main

I wanted to integrate it into my own little project, during a fight, it displays the pokémon in question. Except that these images are huge,

I seriously doubt he made them on his own, so I ask you, do you know how to create these images or do you know the tool he could have used to create my own images with a smaller size?

Thanks !

For the moment, I've tested the command to display pixel arts, but I can't go any further, as I don't know how to reduce the size of the images or create smaller ones.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this online converter: https://asciiart.club/

You can also see this [link](https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/02/20/convert-image-to-ascii-art-masterpiece.html) for more information.

Comment: oh thanks !! It's very nice :)